# uwsgi with gevent takes up 100% CPU

Tags: python, uwsgi, gevent, epoll, netstat

I have some web api server running uwsgi with gevent, 16 processes on 8 core machine. After running several days, some process takes up 100% CPU.

Here is key options of uwsgi

```
master = true
processes = 16
enable-threads=false
min-worker-lifetime = 0
gevent-early-monkey-patch=true
gevent-monkey-patch=true
module = server:app
gevent = 60
```

So I use the pyflame to collect data of the process. 
[pyflame result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZc7k.png)
The result is confusing. 77% of CPU is idle, the rest is run gevent.hub.Hub.run [line: loop.run()].

Then I learned that the system-call is also counted as idle.
So I strace the PID, got the repeated result

```
epoll_wait(20, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=36, u64=30017526431780}}}, 64, 748) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 200961138}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 200981886}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201003573}) = 0
epoll_wait(20, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=36, u64=30017526431780}}}, 64, 748) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201073893}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201093352}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201123285}) = 0
epoll_wait(20, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=36, u64=30017526431780}}}, 64, 748) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201174492}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201192491}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201207349}) = 0
epoll_wait(20, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=36, u64=30017526431780}}}, 64, 748) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201259254}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201279465}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {40805477, 201301453}) = 0
```

I found the u32=36 handle is a udp connection to the dns server. I netstat it and got

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
udp      472      0 local_ip:56273            remote_ip:domain         ESTABLISHED 26223/./uwsgi
```

**The Recv-Q was keep at 472, which looks weird.**

It's seems that the process has been calling epoll_wait cyclically, but has not token data from the kenel buffer.

So, what should I check next?  Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm.. It looks weird, what's the version of uwsgi?

Comment: version of uwsgi: 2.0.14